# Do the batches for the generator and discriminator have to be the same in Adversarial AutoEncoders?

Tags: neural-networks, gan

In Generative Adversarial Networks the generator and discriminator train on different mini-batches, as the noise can be easily sampled at each iteration. But in Adversarial AutoEncoders, it is not clear to me, whether they are trained on the same mini-batch or not. Moreover, some AAE implementations train the discriminator and generator on the same mini-batches.

Does training the discriminator and generator on the same batch lead to better/worse convergence in GANs/AAEs? Intuitively, the information from discriminator's updates would be helpful for generator's updates at the same mini-batch.